# Is it common to use "mule" to refer to stupidity?

Tags: word-usage

Example:

> I'm a mule when it comes to math.

Is this usage common? If not, what other animal or object is more widely used by native English speakers?

Comment: It was a productive metaphor back in the days when people had actual experience with mules.

Comment: Stubbornness is usually associated with mules, and sometimes hardworking. I'd say *ass* is the one you're thinking of.

Comment: ***Dunce*** :   a person who is stupid or slow to learn.

Comment: Hey @Jano what's up.  The simple answer is **no**.  In English, "mule" signifies stubborn.  The sentence given sounds wrong, like it was written by a non-English speaker.  Just as a curiosity, "mule" is also a word used in AmE in the "illegal drug trade" (so if you watch a TV show like *Breaking Bad* or whatever, you'll hear it a lot.)

Comment: Why the hell would anyone vote this question down?  It's a great question.

Comment: You should tell us explicitly what you *are* like in the context of math (do you stubbornly resist being taught, stubbornly persist in trying to learn, or something else?). If you have a [dilletante](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dilettante) attitude, you might be a ***butterfly***. If you voraciously devour all aspects of the subject, perhaps you're a ***gannet***. Etc., etc.

Comment: Well, turkeys are supposedly quite stupid, and the now-extinct dodos had that reputation as well.

Comment: @FumbleFingers the question title makes this quite clear.

Comment: (Just to make it clear:  No, it's not common to use "mule" to imply stupidity.)

Comment: The phrase *"you dumb ox!"* springs to mind, but it refers to people who are big, strong and stupid. There are many English expressions for stupidity (e.g. *dumb as a bag of hammers"*), but (strangely) not many of them use animals.

Comment: ...Oh, and *dinosaur* refers to a person whose thinking is deeply and irredeemably outdated.

Comment: A stump is another popular object of comparison for dumbness in common usage.

Answer (score 18):

The idiom usually associated with mules is stubborness

> **[stubborn as a mule](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stubborn+as+a+mule)**
>   Extremely obstinate, as in *He's stubborn as a mule about wearing a suit and tie.* This simile evokes the proverbial stubbornness of mules, whose use as draft animals was once so common that the reputation for obstinacy can hardly be as warranted as the term indicates. [Early 1800s]

Funnily enough, **donkeys** are considered to be stupid animals. Think of Pinocchio and his donkey ears (and tail) that appeared when he played truant (AmEng *played hooky*) from school.

[image]

If the OP wishes to express someone's ignorance of math, I would suggest using a different expression.

> I'm a complete idiot when it comes to math.

Alternatively, the noun [*numbskull*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/numbskull) is also very appropriate.

*a stupid person; dolt; blockhead*

> I'm a numbskull when it comes to math.

<sub>Source: Tne Free Dictionary</sub>

Comment: Pinocchio in depicted as a donkey because of the Italian  ***somaro*** (donkey) meaning dunce, ass.

Comment: In Italian the *"sei un asino"* (you're a donkey/ass) is also commonly heard.

Comment: Can confirm for Spanish ["Eres un asno"] as well.

Comment: Normally I'd say: "playing truant" and leave it at that, it means a (healthy) student who doesn't go to school, but because they are many non-native speakers on ELU, I felt constrained to add the redundant "from school". I don't feel it is particularly wrong per se, but why use four words when two are sufficient? I also added *hooky* for our American friends. So, you could say I'm repeating myself three times!

Answer (score 4):

Suggest *birdbrain* (informal noun):

- a silly or stupid person

  [Source: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com)]
- a human who gives the impression of possessing a bird-size brain; a fool

  [Source: [The Routledge Dictionary for Modern American Slang and Unconventional English, 2009](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5F-YNZRv-VMC&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=bird*brain%20slang&source=bl&ots=mjvX0C9HXr&sig=vBU8_IwtAswoGOXVzskv6S87TP4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDMQ6AEwCGoVChMI0PK9pIXvxwIVyAoaCh29DgH8#v=onepage&q=bird*brain%20slang&f=false)]

Example sentence:

> '*I'm such a birdbrain when it comes to math(s).*'

A comprehensive list of synonyms for [birdbrain](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5F-YNZRv-VMC&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=bird*brain%20slang&source=bl&ots=mjvX0C9HXr&sig=vBU8_IwtAswoGOXVzskv6S87TP4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDMQ6AEwCGoVChMI0PK9pIXvxwIVyAoaCh29DgH8#v=onepage&q=bird*brain%20slang&f=false) is available through the online M-W Thesaurus

Answer (score 3):

Mule, Donkey, and Ass (animal) are all used to denote stubbornness, lack of intelligence, or lack of empathy for others.

"That person is a donkey."
Insult to that person's intelligence. Could also be used when a person is being socially clumsy. If you witness a person being very loud at a restaurant, calling them a donkey to your friend would be appropriate.

"What an ass"
Insult to a person's sensitivity to another. If a driver cuts you off in traffic, that person is an ass. This one is a bit conflated with asshole - be careful with its use. Not everyone will hear Mule when you say Ass. Many in the US will assume you are talking about the anus.

"Don't be such a mule"
Insult to a persons unwillingness to change (stubbornness) or intellect. Often a part of a longer description: "that person is as stubborn as a mule".

Comment: As an American English speaker, I've personally never heard "donkey" used like that. I also wouldn't find the phrase "What an ass" to be particularly unusual, and actually "What an asshole" seems more common and to me is just a harsher version of the former. I would not think you were literally referring to someone's anus in either case.

Comment: This answer needs some references to authoritative sources.

Answer (score 3):

In Asimov's *Foundation* series of books, a character named *Mule* has the notion of *strength* associated to his name, as in some sort of *brute force*, but never the notion of *lack of intelligence*.

If you really want to use an animal in your specific phrase, you could try something like:

> I'm like a *fish out of water* when it comes to math.

Or some other expression, but this is not directly related to your question title.

Comment: In those books The Mule was also revealed to be infertile (like most mules) so this is a connotation you may wish to avoid. *"I'm not very fertile when it comes to math."*

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a standard animal/object/phrase that would naturally fit the gap in *I'm a ___ when it comes to math* except for something dull like *I'm a **dunce** when it comes to math*.

If you're looking for something a bit more poetic, in British English, you can combine the informal colloquialism *thick* (meaning *stupid*) with a standard simile for emphasis and comic impact, e.g. *as thick as two short planks* or *as thick as mince* (the latter is perhaps specific to Scotland).

So if you wanted a nice idiomatic, albeit very informal, British English way to express your innumeracy you could say:

*I'm as thick as two short planks when it comes to maths.*

(Of course in British English we say *maths* rather than *math*.)

Comment: +1 there is no single animal name that fits into that space in American English and makes unambiguous sense.

Answer (score 2):

Others have well addressed the *mule* question.

As to animal terms used to convey stupidity, consider *[dodo](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=dodo)*

> 3. (Informal) A stupid person; an idiot.

*American Heritage Dictionary*

Answer (score 2):

These days *mule* is used more often to mean a courier who carries and delivers something illegal like drugs across borders and past checkpoints. Even though other connotations for *mule* still stand, using the word for anything other than *illegal courier* invites confusion and a bump in your reader's experience, which should be as smooth as possible.

Mari-Lou A makes a good point that a mule is considered more *stubborn* than *stupid*.

Many others have suggested other animals for stupidity, but you also might want to keep in mind that most of these are hackneyed clichés. You'd do well to forge your own expression for stupidity.

Finally please note that while *dumb* has through misuse come to mean *stupid*, it originally means a person who does not speak and who is therefore considered stupid. Since *dumb* evokes this bit of wrong and insensitive thinking, it too is best avoided.

Comment: This is a nice summary. There may have been a time where _mule_ connoted stupidity ([etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=mule&searchmode=term) says, _meaning "obstinate, stupid, or stubborn person" is from 1470s_), but that meaning seems to have waned while the notion of stubborness has held fast.

Comment: +1 _dumb has through misuse come to mean stupid, it originally means a person who does not speak and who is therefore considered stupid. Since dumb evokes this bit of wrong and insensitive thinking, it too is best avoided_

Answer (score 0):

In Canada, we used to say "bobo". For instance, "Don't be such a bobo!" or I suppose, "I'm a bobo at math."

I don't know why... ;)

Comment: Because *bobo* is Spanish for clown or dunce.

Comment: @tchrist _Somewhat_ less insulting than "idiota".

Answer (score 0):

Why restrict yourself to animals?

You could say something like, "when it comes to math, I'm just one of the Pid Brothers, but I'm not sure which one: Mo, Ron or Stu."

Or, if you prefer brevity, how about, "I'm a mathoron."

There's always, "I'm no Albert Einstein when it comes to math."

Be inventive, and that will distract from your math liabilities.

Answer (score -1):

**Answer**

No, we don't use 'mule' with that meaning. However the term 'jackass' is commonly used especially in the USA.

**Explanation**

If you look for mule in an English dictionary you will see that it can mean a stubborn person or someone who carries drugs. It does not specifically signify stupidity in English.

> mule
>         noun \ˈmyül\ Definition of MULE
>
> 1 a :  a hybrid between a horse and a donkey; especially :  the
>   offspring of a male donkey and a mare b :  a self-sterile plant
>   whether hybrid or not c :  a usually sterile hybrid 2 :  **a very
>   stubborn person**
>
> :  a machine for simultaneously drawing and twisting fiber into yarn
>   or thread and winding it into cops 4 slang :  **a person who smuggles
>   or delivers illicit substances** (as drugs)
>
> [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mule)

In British English, calling someone an 'ass' is distinct from 'arse'. The British meaning of 'ass' refers to the animal and is another word for a donkey. It means a stupid person. However it is little used these days because of the conflict in meaning with American English where 'ass' means 'backside'.

The difference is explained in more detail here. [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ass)

Another term - also outdated - is donkey.

I the USA they currently use the term '**jackass**' to mean a foolish person. [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jackass)

I am not aware of a current British word for fool that uses the name of an animal. However we do understand the US term jackass.

Comment: But jackass isn't used to connote stupidity, just being a jerk. No one would ever say "a jackass at math" unless every time they finish a problem they leap up and fart in a classmates' face or something.